# Ability to create Site templates from Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, save-as-template

Is there a way to create Site templates from a subsite?I do know that we cannot "Save Site as template" when Publishing feature is enabled. Also, getting directly to "/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx is not a supported methodology. Can anyone let me know how we can create templates from a subsite? We would be using a lot of content types which we would use for many sites that are going to be created. So we wanted to save site as template and create sites as and when we need and not redo all them.

Help is appreciated.

Vj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save as template does not work for publishing enabled sites.

edit: Here is an official MS-Not-Supported statement:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2007/09/19/save-site-as-template-option-and-the-publishing-feature/

[...]is: saving publishing enabled sites as a template is not supported and it does not work. You cannot use this option to create new sites. Instead you should create site definitions (..\web server extensions\12\template\SiteTemplates) and provision the new site based on such a site definition. [...]

Comment: Can you think of a alternative where I can save site as a template but still use the features that Publishing provides?

Comment: Short answer is not to use publishing. For this we have a clear not supported statement from MS

Answer (score 0):

can you try to enable the property `'SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled'` with powershell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://contoso/site/subsite1/subsite2/
$web.AllProperties['SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled'] = 'true'
$web.Update()
```

and then access to `/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx`

Comment: Thanks for your response Lucas! Is it a supported method? By doing this, can we utilize all the features that we need for a site once we create another site using this template? We are planning to create many sites using the same template that we create. Since publishing sites don't have this enabled, we can set it to True and save the site as template. In the long run, will it support every aspect?